# generate 2D numpy array containing tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, interpolation

I want to generate a 2D numpy array filled with tuples. Each square represents a pixel, which is related to another 2D coordinate  with the tuple.
I only know a few couples pixel/tuple.
So my array has to interpolate those points, and has to be somehow linear elsewhere.
I have begun with this :

```
rows, cols : nb of rows and columns that the 2D array should have
maxx, maxy : maximum of the x and y real coordinates. Their range is [0:maxx] and [0:maxy]
interpolation = [((row1,col1),(x1,y1)),((row2,col2),(x2,y2))]
X = (rows-1-np.mgrid[0:rows,0:cols][0])/(rows-1)*maxx
Y = np.mgrid[0:rows,0:cols][1]/(cols-1)*maxy
return np.vstack(([X.T], [Y.T])).T
```

But there are no tuples in the grid, and the couples don't interpolate properly the coordinates. Actually the tuples are the centers of circles on a grid, like this  one : [image: calibration grid for opencv]
And I know the real coordinates of all circles. My goal is to have a matrix with all the real coordinates of the pixels of an image, so as to make a 3d scanner :-) 
Does anyone have an idea please ?
Thank you !

Comment: You want an array that contains the indices of the center point of all the dots?

Comment: Watch out for integer division

Comment: A small sample array of numbers would be clearer than your image.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want `tuples`, or just a 3d array?  You can make a 2d array with 'tuples' as elements, but that's a structured array.  Looks more like you want an array that is `(rows, cols, 2)` in shape?

Integer division may be biting you.

```
In [282]: rows, cols = 5.,6.  # make float
In [283]: maxx, maxy = 80.,100.
In [284]: X = (rows-1-np.mgrid[0:rows,0:cols][0])/(rows-1)*maxx
In [285]: Y = np.mgrid[0:rows,0:cols][1]/(cols-1)*maxy
In [288]: np.vstack(([X.T],[Y.T]))  
Out[288]: 
array([[[  80.,   60.,   40.,   20.,    0.],
        [  80.,   60.,   40.,   20.,    0.],
        [  80.,   60.,   40.,   20.,    0.],
        [  80.,   60.,   40.,   20.,    0.],
        [  80.,   60.,   40.,   20.,    0.],
        [  80.,   60.,   40.,   20.,    0.]],

       [[   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
        [  20.,   20.,   20.,   20.,   20.],
        [  40.,   40.,   40.,   40.,   40.],
        [  60.,   60.,   60.,   60.,   60.],
        [  80.,   80.,   80.,   80.,   80.],
        [ 100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.]]])
```

I left off the final `.T` because (2,6,5) displays more compactly. `np.array([X,Y]).transpose([1,2,0])` should do the same as your `vstack`.

Is this what you want?

`mgrid` can do the interpolation with the `j` parameter:

```
In [307]: Y,X=np.mgrid[0:100:6j,80:0:5j]
In [308]: np.array([X,Y])
```

`np.linspace` is also handy.  Look also at `ogrid` and `meshgrid`.